# Can TortoiseGit manage a local repository created by something else?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I'm using GitHub for Windows, which keeps the repositories for the projects I copied locally in a special directory.  I also have TortoiseGit installed.

I see the special SCM icons on the project folders.  There was something on one of those projects I wanted to handle with TortoiseGit.  It sort-of worked, but I stopped trying.  Now there is a persistent stop-exclamation icon on that folder, even after going back to the GitHub to do several updates.  I'm guessing that the only way to get rid of it is to make TortoiseGit properly work with GitHub checkouts.

It was until after I messed around that I realized that GitHub and TortoiseGit keep the hash-keys to their repositories to themselves, so cross-access is probably a bad idea....

Any way to make them work together, or at least clean up my icon error.  (It would be nice if I could list my GitHub repos on the "Git" section of Libraries.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different git tools, like *GitHub for Windows* and *TortoiseGit*, should work fine together (and do for me). They can both handle git repositories created by another tool.

*TortoiseGit* bases the information represented by the icons in Explorer on the information it gets from the `.git` directory, that contains the local git repository.

One confusing aspect is that both tools use `git.exe` in the background to do git operations, but they may use different `git.exe`:s. *GitHub for Windows* uses one installed in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\bin\git.exe`, while *TortoiseGit* normally uses one installed by [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20official%20git). That could create problems if they are different versions. Update both to the latest versions.

Comment: From the GitHub internals, I got "git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1" when running "git --version".  For TortoiseGit, the About screen gave me "TortoiseGit 1.8.3.0 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe)" and "git version 1.8.3-rc3 (C:\msysgit\bin)".  Both GitHub for Windows (Version 1.0.48.0 (5e3c587512469a0360d1ec3def9136ad169bd5df)) and TortoiseGit report being up to date.